# Eclipse CDT indexer lost after system update

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse on Ubuntu for C++ development. After updating from Ubuntu 11.04 to Ubuntu 11.10, Eclipse indexer no longer is able to find my C/C++ system headers and annoys me filling the whole editor view with small bugs symbols, one for every line with an `#include` or symbol it does not recognizes.

Downloading and unpacking a brand new Eclipse CDT package will not solve the problem. Creating the Hello World sample project will not solve it either. I have tried to add by hand all system paths to the indexer configurations, and it partially solved the problem to that specific project, but only standard C headers and installed libraries were indexed (i.e. I was unable to make it work with standard C++ headers like `iostream`).

I believe there must be some configuration hidden in my system messing with Eclipse's indexer...

How can I make Eclipse to have its old behavior, automatically finding system headers when I create a new Hello World project, and specially, when working on my existing projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem explanation in Eclipse CDT forum: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/247954/

To solve it locally for a project, open the project "Properties" window, under "C/C++ Build"→"Environment" add a new variable:
- Name: LC_ALL
- Value: C

This will make the compiler to issue its messages in English.