# eclipse CDT 8.01 - default paths (libstdc,libstdc++) totally disappeared in 'includes' directory

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I tried to remove all the files and temporal files in ~/.eclipse and re-install eclipse+cdt. But those default paths did not appear again.

I went to the 'c/c++ general'->'paths and symbols' and hoped to check the 'show build-in values' to recover these paths, but it also did not work.

This is very annoying since I need to manually add those paths every time when creating a new c/c++ projection to prevent the indexer from reporting parsing errors even when calling some standard functions, though it actually does not cause compile problem.

Can any one tell me how to let CDT automatically find these default paths. Thanks!

I'm using

```
 kubuntu 11.10
 Indigo+cdt8.01
 g++ 4.6.1
```

Comment: It seems a bug in Indigo, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144751/eclipse-cdt-indexer-lost-after-system-update

Answer (score 1):

Have you cleaned up your workspace and created a completely new project?

Comment: This happened to me with Juno when the projects were created for the first time by Juno. Steps:
1) Install Juno
2) Create hello-world Makefile-based project
3) Observe that "puts" is given the dreaded red underline and include stdio.h is also flagged.
Note: gcc was in fact installed at the proper location so /usr/include/stdio.h did in fact exist.