# Eclipse C++ inline type checking failing to find libstdc++ classes

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have eclipse installed with CDT on windows(7) . I installed MinGW. I pointed my include files directory at

c:\MinGW

I started a simple project with a class that basically just includes `<string>` and `<iostream>`

The "hint icons" in the gutter are telling me that `<iostream>` and `<string>` are unresolved includes, but make is building my project just fine. This problem is subsequently leading to my definitions that rely on string not getting recognized.

How do I resolve the problem so that the IDE recognizes the includes the same way make does?

This is eclipse 3.7.1 .

Comment: I reviewed this link: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/247954/ and this other stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144751/eclipse-cdt-indexer-lost-after-system-update , tried both, and neither worked to get my index recognizing the includes

Comment: Usually the compiler root C:\MinGW does not contain the header files but some directory C:\MinGW\Include. Did the specify the directory that actually has the files?